# Need some help to Install own E-mail server. mx record

Tags: email, dns, cpanel

can someone explain and give some instructions. im new for this and i don't know how to do.

I have domain and E-mail hosting in providers server.

> Domain: www.mydomain.com, 
>   mx IP: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd

Now i need to send/receive emails from my own server, where i have installed Mdaemon.

> > My local domain is: mydomain.local

Q:
What i should to do on the server and How , and what in Domain (Cpanel)

> My ext IP is : qqq.www.eee.rrr

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a static IP address.  If you have an internet account that uses Cpanel, chances are you do not.  Your ISP can sell you an upgrade from dynamic to static.

Which mail server platform do you intend to utilize?

Comment: I have static IP /29 . Mdaemon Server.